# CaseSenstive Table names

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, yii, case-sensitive

hi there i made track star application and everything works fine except for one issue that i face error 
`CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'devnmark_root.AuthAssignment' doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM 'AuthAssignment'
WHERE userid=:userid`

now this was automatically generated by Yii when i checked for `if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('createUser',array('project'=>$model)))
18 {
19     $this->menu[] = array('label'=>'Add User To Project','url'=>array('adduser', 'id'=>$model->id));
20 }`

then i went to phpmyadmin and executed this query manually

`SELECT * FROM`AuthAssignment`WHERE userid=4` and there is error which says same that table does not exist.

if i use small case letter for table name then no error.

i executed same query on local wamp 's phpmyadmin same query does not show any error there so this is clear that there is error with my sql .any idea what can i do to solve?

Comment: maybe phpmyadmin is using strtolower(), check the collation of your database to see if it's case sensitive: show create database your_db_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you hitting up SQL_MODE documentation for setting your final options.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

For testing you can just do a:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Or adjust your command line:

```
--sql-mode=""
```

Comment: The other option that effects table name casing would be the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html options for lower_case_table_names variable.

Comment: edit your my.cnf file and add a line "set-variable = lower_case_table_names=1" and then restart your mysqld process.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set the system variable [*lower_case_table_names*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) to 1.

Answer (score 1):

My local application was developed under Windows, howerver production is under Linux and I caused the same problem.
For me it happened because of case sensitivity - table **AuthAssignment** in database was actually **authassignment**.

I have found two options to solve it:
rename database table from authassignment to AuthAssignment
or
edit config file component section:

```
'components'=>array(
...
    'user'=>array(...
    ),
    'authManager'=>array(
     ...
     'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment' //THIS LINE SOLVED MY PROBLEM
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of non-existent authassignment table, I had forgotten running the rights installation which in my case was by following URL i.e.

/index.php/rights/install

and then the setup was like a breeze and self explanatory :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this answer helped the most: [original source](http://tahiryasin.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/solution-table-mydb-authassignment-doesnt-exist/).

In the authManager in config/main.php you can add lowercased names of the tables like this:

```sql
'components'=>array(
    'authManager'=>array(
        'defaultRoles'=>array('guest'),
        'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
        'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment',
        'itemTable'=>'authitem',
        'rightsTable'=>'rights',
        'itemChildTable'=>'authitemchild',
),
```